# Expanded child use all width of screen

Tags: flutter, dart

The problem I have is that the second element in the column is expanding to full screen. I tried changing expanded to flexible, but that didn't help. I need this element to have a fixed width.

How can this be fixed?

.............................................................................................

main.dart:

```
import 'package: flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:exif/exif.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(home: MyApp()),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final mapController = MapController();
  static LatLng _initialPosition = LatLng(0, 0);
  List<Map<String, IfdTag>> exifDataList = [];
  List<File> selectedPhotos = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            FlutterMap(
              options: MapOptions(
                center: _initialPosition,
                zoom: 14.0,
              ),
              children: [
                TileLayer(
                  urlTemplate: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                  userAgentPackageName: 'dev.fleaflet.flutter_map.example',
                ),
                MarkerLayer()
              ],
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                TextButton(
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    // ...
                                  },
                                  child: Text('Import GPX'),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          // Display EXIF data
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  TextButton(
                                    style: ButtonStyle(
                                      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                                        type: FileType.custom,
                                        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png'],
                                        allowMultiple: true,
                                      );
                                      if (result != null) {
                                        // Get the list of selected files
                                        List<File> files = result.paths.map((path) => File(path!)).toList();

                                        for (File file in files) {
                                          // Read EXIF data for each file
                                          List<int> fileBytes = await file.readAsBytes();
                                          Map<String, IfdTag> exifData = await readExifFromBytes(fileBytes);

                                          // Use exifData for further processing or displaying information
                                          print('EXIF data for file ${file.path}: $exifData');

                                          setState(() {
                                            selectedPhotos.add(file);
                                          });
                                        }
                                      }
                                    },
                                    child: Text('Select photos'),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                            Expanded(
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: selectedPhotos.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  File photo = selectedPhotos[index];
                                  String fileName = path.basename(photo.path);
                                  return Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                                        boxShadow: [
                                          BoxShadow(
                                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                            spreadRadius: 2,
                                            blurRadius: 5,
                                            offset: Offset(0, 3),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      child: ListTile(
                                        leading: Container(
                                          width: 40,
                                          height: 40,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                            image: DecorationImage(
                                              image: FileImage(photo),
                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        title: Text(fileName),
                                        trailing: IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              selectedPhotos.removeAt(index);
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                TextButton(
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    // ...
                                  },
                                  child: Text('Process'),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



Future<String> getExifFromFile(image) async {
  if (image == null) {
    return "";
  }

  var bytes = await image!.readAsBytes();
  var tags = await readExifFromBytes(bytes);
  var sb = StringBuffer();

  tags.forEach((k, v) {
    sb.write("$k: $v \n");
  });

  return sb.toString();
}
```

App:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your ListTile to your preferred size, otherwise, it would take parent width as the preferred width, in your case, it would take ListBuilder Width

```dart
ListView.builder(
  builder:(context,index){
   return SizeBox(
            width:20,
            child: YourListTile()
          );
    }
  )
```